# Signed distance function about a circular arc

Tags: functions, analytic-geometry

I have a rectangle of 1.3 mm * 0.2 mm, take the origin to the lower left corner of the rectangle. Say, I have a circular arc defined by the (0.3,0),(0.2732,0.1) & (0.3,0.2). It has a radius of 0.2 mm & center of the circular arc is (0.4732,0.1)

Now, imagine that the circular arc has a thickness of $\epsilon = 0.0002$

I want to define a signed distance function such that $\phi$ is 0 to the left of the left interface (or the arc), smoothly varies between 0 and 1 within the interface, and 1 beyond the right interface.

This is what I tried:

$d(x,y) = \sqrt{(x-x_{center})^2 + (y-y_{center})^2} - radius$

$\phi = \frac{1}{1+\exp(\frac{d}{\epsilon})}$

I am getting the following variation:

[[image: <span class=]$\phi$ as per above Equation" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JetH2.png)

However, I want this to be the result

[[image: Expected result for <span class=]$\phi$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhySN.png)

How do I approach this differently to get the target function ?

Code for the plot(s):

```
import numpy as np

def level_set_function(x, y, x_center, y_center,radius,epsilon):
    d = np.sqrt((x-x_center)**2 + (y-y_center)**2) - radius
    phi = 1/(1+np.exp(d/epsilon))
    
    return phi

# Define constants
epsilon = 0.0002
x_center = 0.4732
y_center = 0.1
radius = 0.2

x = np.linspace(0, 1.3, 100)


y = np.ones_like(x) * y_center

phi = level_set_function(x, y, x_center, y_center,radius, epsilon)

# phi[x>0.4] = 1

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))

ax.plot(x, phi)
ax.set_xlabel('x ')
ax.set_ylabel('ϕ')
ax.set_title('ϕ along y=0.1')
plt.show()
```

Comment: That graph did not come from the function you defined above it. Either the description you gave of $\phi$ is wrong or how you are calculating $\phi$ is wrong, or how you are graphing $\phi $ is wrong. Also FYI, use `$\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$` to get $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

Comment: It seems to be right, I have added the code for the plot above, please check.

Comment: I see - the 0.0002 makes the curvature of the actual function too small for the graph to handle. You are actually getting what you want with this graph. You are just forgetting that the line $y = 0.1$ intersects the circle twice, and thus crosses the interface twice. Inside the circle, $\phi$ is approximately $1$, outside it is approximately $0$, and it swaps between them in the 0.0002 width of the interface. It is just that the line is inside the circle for that range.